# Android change toolbar color and status bar color but keep statusbar shadow

Tags: java, android

I'd like to keep the shadow on the status bar
but I need to programmatically change the toolbar and status bar color.
I can do this, but if I programmatically set the status bar color, it loses the shadow (I believe it's the elevation)

I have `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` on my root (coordlayout)
I have this as my theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Im setting the toolbar color:

```
mToolbar.setBackgroundColor((Color.parseColor("#FF4040")));
```

How do I set both without losing the shadow?

[default status bar color with shadow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYakq.png)

[setting the second color on toolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTUGi.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
     android:elevation="1"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
```

Comment: Please add more information regarding the use of this piece of code